# Poisson Disk Sampling on a real dataset

Tags: python

I have seen lots of people implementing the 'Fast Poisson Disk Sampling' algorithm a.k.a Bridson ([Paper of the algorithm](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Erbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf), [python Code](https://github.com/emulbreh/bridson/)).
However, I haven't found anyone implementing it on a real dataset. Let's say, someone has a predefined dataset.

[image: Image of the distribution]

I would like to give my poisson disk algorithm the coordinates of the points with the amount of points I want to sample with a certain condition on the radius. Has anyone done this before? Is it doable? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it just me, or this graph looks 3D....!

Comment: @YaakovBressler hehe. No it is a 2D scatter plot, however maybe the effects of the colors play a role in making it look 3D.

Comment: I don't think your question makes sense.  Fast Poisson Disk Sampling is a way to generate a dataset.  What does it mean to apply such a method to an existing dataset?  It's like saying "generate 10 random numbers between 0 and 100 for me, but generate them based on these 10 numbers I already have".

Comment: @Steve Indeed. The algorithm generates data. However, what I am asking for is, how can make the algorithm sample data from an existing dataset using the same technique. So basically, the points sampled will be separated from each others by a certain distance/radius of a circle.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I think I getcha.  I wouldn't call this an implementation of Fast Poisson Disk Sampling.  Rather, it seems to me that what you're really wanting to do is run the standard Fast Poisson Disk Sampling algorithm, but then use the results of that to pull points out of your existing dataset.  For each of the generated samples, you want to return the real data point that is closest to that sample, and within a given distance from the sample. Does that sum it up?

Comment: @Steve that is also a nice idea. However, what I am thinking of is
1. Choose a random point
2. Start expanding to its neighbors based on a certain radius
3. End it when the required amount is met (if possible, total convergence), if not possible to meet the total amount required, just return as much points as possible

Comment: @Steve I was able to make the code and it works fine. You give it a radius, the amount of points needed for sampling (N) and a predefined dataset. I will be sharing my code for help in optimization later on.

Comment: @ombk - cool!  I'm glad you figured this out.  I expect that if you share your work, it will be helpful to others.

Comment: @Steve Done! it is ok to post a github link? I am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code with examples posted on my github.

[Poisson Disk Sampling](https://github.com/omarbak/Imbalanced-data/blob/master/KernelSup-PDS/poisson%20disk%20sampling.ipynb)

The code is not finalized yet, however, so far it works.

***Random Sampling.***
[image: Random Sampling of 100 points (N=500)]

***Poisson Disc Sampling***
[image: Poisson Disc Sampling 100 points (N=500)]

Comment: Your GitHub link is dead.

Comment: file is still there: https://github.com/omarbak/Imbalanced-data/blob/master/KernelSup-PDS/poisson_disk_sampling.ipynb